# PHP populate form element with url ONLY IF url parameter is present

Tags: php

I've started with a standard form select option that looks like this:

```
<option value="">All Locations</option>
```

I was able to re-use a URL parameter using _get to create an option from a value like this: &location=Bellingham

```
<?php
$location = $_GET['location'];
?>

<option value='<?php echo $location; ?>'><?php echo $location; ?></option>
```

How do I using PHP test for location value being populated  and if so using my _GET option and if not falling back to my standard form select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you mean, but these seems a bit more logical compared to my original answer...

```
<form>
    <select>
        <option value="">All Locations</option>
        <?php if(isset($_GET['location']) && !empty($_GET['location'])):?>
        <option selected value='<?php echo $_GET['location']; ?>'><?php echo $_GET['location']; ?></option>
        <?php endif?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Is this what you meant?
Feel free to ask questions should something be unclear.

Comment: Pefect...isset, I tried a variation of this without the !empty.  Thanks so much!  Happy New Year!

Comment: Same to you, why have you chosen for such a method instead of multiple values known ahead of time and then simply selecting one that matches the $_GET['location']?

Comment: The values are part of a wordpress database using meta-data and impossible to extract or query on traditionally.  This was the only way I could think of to retrieve this value...the rest of the options populate using wordpress queries.

Answer (score 2):

are you manually sending the location in the get request?

try putting all the location in the a table and then use mysql

```html
<?php

mysql_connect('hostname', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('database-name');

$sql = "SELECT location_name FROM location";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='location'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['location_name'] . "'>" . $row['location_name'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```